# Disable splash screen when launching MATLAB 2014b on Mac OSX

Tags: macos, matlab

I'm wondering if there is any way to disable the MATLAB splash screen when launching the app on Mac OS X (i.e. by just clicking on the app, without launching it from the command line).

I know that there is an option to disable the splash screen on Windows systems (see [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_env/startup-options.html)). It also seems to be possible if I launch MATLAB from the command line (by using the -nosplash flag). That said, I can't find anything related to the general Mac OS X case.

Just FYI I am currently running Mac OS X 10.10 with MATLAB 2014b.

Comment: I don't use OS X, but is it possible to define some batch/script file that is run when clicked on? (like a `.bat` file in Windows). In that case, you could define that script to call Matlab with the `-nosplash` flag.

Comment: I do use OS X, but I'm curious why one would need this? Your question is answered here at SuperUser.StackExchange: [How do I pass command line arguments to Dock items?](http://superuser.com/questions/271678/how-do-i-pass-command-line-arguments-to-dock-items)